# Blank line added at top of first CSS multi-column

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS columns, but seem to have an issue where the beginning of the text has an extra space at the top, making the subsequent second and third columns appear higher than the first column.

I thought I had it all pretty basic. I did already try removing the margin-bottom for the h2, but that didn't seem to affect the columns. So I put the h2 into its own div, but that also didn't affect them. Oddly, it looks fine in DreamWeaver, just not when live on the server. 
It seems to do this in Safari, FireFox, and Opera. I do not have Chrome or IE.

Here is the link to the site so you can see it: [www.jordanmiller.newbedesign.com/coast/academics.html](http://www.jordanmiller.newbedesign.com/coast/academics.html)

Below is the CSS that is used with the columns:

```
h2 {
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: -.5%;
    font-color: #003;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
}
div.text {
    margin: 2% auto;
    max-width: 900px;
}
div.texthead {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.col {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1%; /* Saf3, Chrome*/
  -moz-column-count: 3;   
  -moz-column-gap: 1%; /* FF3.5+ */
  column-count: 3;        
  column-gap: 1%; /* Opera 11+*/
  text-align: left;
}
```

And below here is the HTML for the content:

```
<div class="texthead">
<h2>Academics: Not Just Books</h2>
</div>

<div class="text">
<div class="col"><p>Coast Middle School is a community of active learners working in concert for the development of individual success and self-esteem. It employs a comprehensive curriculum that seeks to develop the whole child--intellectually, physically, spiritually, socially, aesthetically, and emotionally. Teachers and students in Coast Middle School hold themselves and each other to the highest expectations. The Middle School academically challenges its students in foreign language, math, social studies, language arts, and science, while at the same nurturing emotional and creative development through our acclaimed fine arts and athletic programs.</p>

<p>Coast Middle School is developmentally responsive to the needs of its students. The Middle School provides the students with teachers and specialized professionals who are readily available to offer the assistance students need in negotiating their lives, both in and out of school. As a complement to their academic classes, students discuss issues relevant to their lives through our comprehensive character education and guidance curriculum. The student-led vestry program allows the students to develop a sense of leadership and responsibility as they aid the chaplain in the development of chapel messages.</p>

<p>Coast Middle School seeks to conceptualize and promote the healthy growth of young adolescents as ethical citizens and increasingly competent, self-sufficient young people who are optimistic about the future. To achieve these goals the Middle School is structured on a team concept. Each grade level is split into two teams--blue and white, representing our school colors--consisting of four academic core classes. Coast Middle School believes academic success and personal growth increase markedly when young adolescents' affective needs are met. Therefore, all adults in the Middle School are advocates, advisors, and mentors for each student. Each team works together on service-learning activities and experiential learning opportunities.</p>

<p>Coast Middle School feels strongly that the most successful learning strategies are ones that involve each student personally. Therefore, we offer after-school tutorials so students can get personalized help with homework or as preparation for a test or quiz. Other after-school possibilities include intramurals, clubs, and an Extended Day Program, which runs until 6:00 p.m. Students are also encouraged to participate on school athletic teams. Students in both grades can participate in drama performances.</p>

<p>Coast Middle School is also actively invested in the impact media and digital activities have on our students’ lives. Students in both grades participate in a Digital Citizenship curriculum provided by Common Sense Media, which encourages them to be safe, responsible, and savvy citizens of the digital world.</p>

<p><strong>Seventh Grade:</strong> While enjoying a similar daily schedule in seventh grade, the students make a choice from four languages (Chinese, French, Latin, or Spanish) for daily study. Additionally they choose one elective (see course descriptions). The seventh grade takes a class trip to Washington, D.C. Each of the three sports seasons includes at least one no-cut sport.</p>

<p><strong>Eighth Grade:</strong> The daily class schedule includes civics, physical science, algebra or geometry, and English. Interdisciplinary activities include Mock Congress and a social issues research project. All classes emphasize critical and creative thinking. The focus of this grade is leadership training and service learning, as well as preparation to move successfully into the Upper School. The eighth grade travels to New York City in the spring.</p>

<p>Students in both grades have a morning fruit break and break for a brief recess to socialize and develop friendships that are vital in the development of a young adolescent. Band, chorus, and orchestra are offered in bith grades, along with visual and theater arts opportunities.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think adding this to your css solves the problem:

```
div.col p{
    margin-top:0px;
}
```